# Q: how to insert space between the footnote and the bottomrule table?

Tags: tables, captions

In this case, the footnote "\caption*{*Porcentaje de Tweets respecto a la muestra. \ La relación tweet:hashtag suele ser de tipo 1:n.\Muestra $=$ 2.507.027 tweets}" is too close to the table body. My intention is to separate it from the *bottomrule* with a similar distance the caption is from the *toprule* and to aply this for all the tables. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{thesis}
%document hosted here, see sample ch.1: https://es.sharelatex.com/project/58455964c0ba0b593dc919de

\begin{document}



\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{Principales hashtags del movimiento 15M}
\label{tab:hashtags15M}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrr@{}}\toprule[1.5pt]
\bf Hashtag & \bf Tweets & \bf Ratio*  \\\midrule
 acampadasol & 646.853 & 25,80\\
 spanishrevolution & 605.764 & 24,16\\
 15m & 572.047 & 22.82\\
 nolesvotes & 302.745 & 12,08\\
 democraciarealya & 242.903 & 9,69\\
 nonosvamos & 103.889 & 4,14 \\
 notenemosmiedo & 84.614 & 3,38\\
 yeswecamp & 56.938 & 2,27\\
 19j & 56.622 & 2.26 \\
 globalcamp & 37.024 & 1,48\\
 bcnsinmiedo & 37.024 & 1,48\\
 globalcamp & 35.877 & 1,43\\
 estoesreflexion & 31.220 & 1,25\\
 15mani & 28.891 & 1,15

\bottomrule[1.25pt]
\end {tabular}\par
\caption*{*Porcentaje de Tweets respecto a la muestra. \\
La relación tweet:hashtag suele ser de tipo 1:n.\\Muestra $=$ 2.507.027 tweets}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you use `caption` inspite of `footnote`?

Comment: there is a package, [`ctable`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctable), that provides "table notes". I am not sure if it can be configured to do exactly what you want, but you may want to look at it for inspiration/reference.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Principales hashtags del movimiento 15M}
  \label{tab:hashtags15M}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lrr@{}}
    \toprule[1.5pt]
    \textbf{Hashtag}  & \textbf{Tweets} & \textbf{Ratio}* \\
    \midrule
    acampadasol       & 646.853         & 25,80           \\
    spanishrevolution & 605.764         & 24,16           \\
    15m               & 572.047         & 22.82           \\
    nolesvotes        & 302.745         & 12,08           \\
    democraciarealya  & 242.903         & 9,69            \\
    nonosvamos        & 103.889         & 4,14            \\
    notenemosmiedo    & 84.614          & 3,38            \\
    yeswecamp         & 56.938          & 2,27            \\
    19j               & 56.622          & 2.26            \\
    globalcamp        & 37.024          & 1,48            \\
    bcnsinmiedo       & 37.024          & 1,48            \\
    globalcamp        & 35.877          & 1,43            \\
    estoesreflexion   & 31.220          & 1,25            \\
    15mani            & 28.891          & 1,15            \\
    \bottomrule[1.25pt]
  \end {tabular}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item[*] Porcentaje de Tweets respecto a la muestra.  La relación
    tweet:hashtag suele ser de tipo 1:n.  Muestra $=$ 2.507.027
    tweets.
  \end{itemize}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]